# Telerik .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Hi i just started to use telerik components.

i use radgrid in aspx page and it has datasourceid:

> ```
> <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$   
> ConnectionStrings:F8CONNECTION %>"   
> ProviderName="Devart.Data.Oracle" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT TANIM
> FROM f8crm_proje_qry" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
> ```

When i publish to server i got an error:

[image]

My web.config:

```
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="F8CONNECTION" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostanme)(PORT=1111))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db)));User Id=user;Password=pass" providerName="ORACLE" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92ceczx1(v=vs.85).aspx

System.Data.OracleClient managed provider requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or higher to be installed on the computer where the ASP.NET Web page runs.

Probably the server does not have the Oracle client installed, but your dev box has it.